# SQL: find items in a db where the string of a field is a substring of the same field of other items

Tags: sql

Having a db with items with field "name", I would need to find those substrings that are repeated many times as substrings in this field. For example, in a db of shops, how many items contain TESCO having names such as TESCO-LONDON, TESCO-MANCHESTER, TESCO-BATH, etc. I would appreciate some help on this, thanks in advance.

The db is huge and it repeats substrings such as TESCO, ALDI, etc.

[image]

Then, I would need to find the substrings that are repeated many times and how many times. An added column would be useful. Expected output:

[image]

Comment: Please tag the DBMS. Also, including sample data and desired output is recommended. Also, please clarify what is "shops", and what is "items"? Do you mean "table" and "column"? The terminology is unclear.

Comment: Do you have a list of these substrings(TESCO, ALDI) somewhere?

Comment: No, I don't. I need to find the substrings that are repeated many times, then compute how many times the substrings are repeated. I have added an example and expected result to make it more clear, thanks!

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since several of your names have punctuation separating the common sequences you want to identify, you can use this to your advantage.  Here is a CTE that identifies the top 50 most common words separated by specified punctuation.  I'm  using REPLACE to get a common punctuation character to split words.  Then you can use the CTE to compare against your data.

```
WITH CommonWords AS (
    SELECT TOP 50 split.SplitData AS CommonWord, COUNT(1) AS occurances
    FROM Grocery
    CROSS APPLY fSplitOn(REPLACE(REPLACE(SHOPNAME, ' ', '-'), '_', '-'), '-') AS split
    GROUP BY split.SplitData
    ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
    )

SELECT TOP 500 c.CommonWord, COUNT(1)
FROM Grocery AS g
INNER JOIN CommonWords AS c ON g.SHOPNAME LIKE '%' + c.CommonWord + '%'
GROUP BY c.CommonWord
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
```

The INNER JOIN with LIKE won't perform very well, but should work if you are not running this frequently.  You might get better performance to replace the CTE with an actual table.

Here is the Table-valued split function I am using.  If your DBMS has one built in, use that instead.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fSplitOn]
(
    @input NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @delimiter NVARCHAR(8)
)
RETURNS @result_set TABLE(SplitData NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @start_position AS INT, @ending_position AS INT
    DECLARE @delimiterLength AS INT = LEN(REPLACE(@delimiter, ' ', '.'))

    SELECT @start_position = 1, @ending_position = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @input)
    WHILE @start_position < LEN(@input) + 1
        BEGIN
            IF @ending_position = 0
                SET @ending_position = LEN(@input) + 1
            INSERT INTO @result_set (SplitData) VALUES
            (SUBSTRING(@input, @start_position, @ending_position - @start_position))
            
            SET @start_position = @ending_position + @delimiterLength
            SET @ending_position = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @input, @start_position)
        END
    RETURN
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `LIKE` keyword and COUNT function.

```sql
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name
WHERE columnN LIKE pattern;
```

E.g. for your situation something like

```sql
SELECT COUNT(items)
FROM shops
WHERE items LIKE '%TESCO%'
```

See [this for how to use the LIKE keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp).
In this case the `%` operator acts as a wildcard matching any string with TESCO in any place.
How to use the [COUNT function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp)

Comment: Sorry, my question may be not clear and I have added an example to clarify, I would need to check this for a whole db, comparing each field name with others and finding substrings common in many items.

Comment: See the edited answer, you will probably need to run the query for each string you want to test.

Comment: That's correct. As the db is huge I would like to find something superefficient that would find the substrings and could count them as in the expected result. Finding all possible substrings and checking them separately in so huge db is very time consuming.

Comment: You may need to consider your data structure. Normally using an index will speed up this query, however since you have to check both sides of the word TESCO you will need to do a full table scan each time, if you can force the system to scan forwards I.e. only using `TESCO%` then a search index will increase your query(s) speed.

Comment: Double quotes are for delimited identifiers. Use single quotes for string literals.